# How to trim everything after - (dash)

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have a host name that i would like to trim everything after the dash then remove numbers at the end. For example, here is a host name

```
axcc91-calpw-11299
```

When the regex is applied to above hostname this will be produced

```
axcc
```

As you can see everything after the dash is removed including the numbers before the dash. How would i acomplish this using a regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^([^-\d]+)
```

Details:

- `^` start of the string
- `(...)` Capturing group to return your match
- `[^-\d]` match everything except a dash or a number

  - `+` one to unlimited times *(greedy)*

[See it Here](https://regex101.com/r/SZ421J/2/)

Comment: I think this returns axcc91 but I need it to return axcc without 91. How can I do that?

Comment: Ahh I misunderstood your question. Updated the pattern @Luke101